# install VMOD basic-auth for Varnish

Tags: varnish, ubuntu-server

Im trying to install the VMOD called basicauth.

This is the repo: https://git.gnu.org.ua/vmod-basicauth.git

There is also a README file which is supposed to help guide you through the process.

It tells you to pull the code, also pull code of varnish (did that with help of `sudo apt-get source varnish` )... I did that, so far so good.

But then Im supposed to do this:

```sh
run:

  ./configure --with-varnish-source=/usr/src/varnish-3.0.1 --with-vmod-dir
```

**THE PROBLEM**

I have been trying to figure out where to find that "configure" script. I have no idea where to find it.

When I look at other tutorials, like [this one](https://newbedev.com/varnish-4-basic-authentication) I guess that it should within the vmod-basicauth folder... but it is not. There is only configure.ac. It tried running that file, but that does not work. **Does anyone of you know how I can install this VMOD?** Any tips or help would be appreciated.

Also: it seems there is only information off very old tutorials and repos... any idea where I could some more up to date infos?

**UPDATE**

I have also downloaded "[The Varnish Book](https://info.varnish-software.com/the-varnish-book)" now, checked on how to isntall "[libvmod-example](https://github.com/varnishcache/libvmod-example)." Within that folder there is a "autogen.sh" file that create the "configure" file. But I also cannot find a any "autogen.sh" in the basicauth package...
Hahha ..... arrrrrrr Im getting nowhere.

Does anyone know where I can find a good tutorial?
Im wokring with ubuntu-server currently. Noticed that redhad has VMODs in their repos, but that won't help me ;)

**SYSTEM INFO**

Here is some more info about my system:

```sh
 dpkg -l | grep varnish
ii  libvarnishapi-dev:amd64              6.2.1-2                                     amd64        development files for Varnish
ii  libvarnishapi2:amd64                 6.2.1-2                                     amd64        shared libraries for Varnish
rc  varnish                              6.2.1-2                                     amd64        state of the art, high-performance web accelerator
```

Serverifno (a local development VM in this case):

[image: ubuntu server info]

Best,
AuthenticPinguin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tested it, and I didn't experience any problems compiling the VMOD.

Here's a step-by-step guide on how to install it.

### 1. Get a recent Varnish version

I'm not sure whether or not you installed Varnish through the Ubuntu packages, but I advise you to install it via the official packages: https://packagecloud.io/varnishcache/.

### 2. Install the build dependencies

Install the required build dependencies by using the following command:

```
apt-get install -y varnish-dev autoconf automake gcc libtool make python3-docutils git
```

Most of these dependencies are trivial, but there's one specific package that might not be found unless you're using the official Varnish package repo. It's `varnish-dev`.

I've tried looking for it natively in the Ubuntu Focal repository, and the closest I came was `libvarnishapi-dev`, but that didn't really work.

> That's why I advise using the official packages from https://packagecloud.io/varnishcache/. The version I prefer is https://packagecloud.io/varnishcache/varnish60lts, because it's the *LTS version*.

### 3. Get the source code

Once you've put all the dependencies in place, you can go ahead and download the VMOD source code by running the following commands:

```
cd /usr/src/
git clone git://git.gnu.org.ua/vmod-basicauth.git
```

As you can see the code will be place in the `/usr/src` directory.

### 4. Compile the code

Now that the source code is on your system, you run the following commands to configure, compile and install the VMOD code:

```
./bootstrap
./configure
make
make install
```

> If `./configure` cannot be found, it means it wasn't properly generated by the `./bootstrap` command. If that happens, have a look at the output of your `./bootstrap` command to figure out what went wrong.

### 5. Import the VMOD

The VMOD has been installed in the proper location, so it's time to import it into your VCL file and use its features.

Here's a VCL example:

```
vcl 4.1;

import basicauth;

sub vcl_recv {
    if (!basicauth.match("/var/www/.htpasswd",req.http.Authorization)) {
        return(synth(401,"Authentication required"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @ThijsFeryn! Will try that immediatly